# include php file then make a call_user_func() doesn't work

Tags: php, file-handling

I have got a little problem.
My script gets module names to include by database. In these files their is just one function (same name as the file name).
My though was that this code should work:

But unfortunately it doesn't work. If I call the function directly it works.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        if(get_user_right('dashboard_'.$row['name']))
        {
            if(file_exists('module/'.$row['name'].'.php'))
            {
                include('module/'.$row['name'].'.php');
                $content .= call_user_func($row['name']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a `'`. Turn on errors.

Comment: sorry, I have shorted the path in the include and file_exists... in the original code their is no syntax error

Comment: This code looks so amazingly exploitable, local file inclusions and code execution all in one, you might want to check what functions are called and what files are included before doing so, all I have to do is inject a row into your database and it's game over

Comment: _"But unfortunately it doesn't work"_ - So what happens? Nothing? Errors? Have you debugged the code to see if any of the if-statements fail? Please update your question with a more detailed description of what _"doesn't work"_ means.

Comment: @Paradoxis your right -> this is not save... but it is just a local application... EDIT: the included files just display statics... so nothing actually to worry about

Comment: @MagnusEriksson no errors are returned or displayed. The called function just returns 'abcd' at the moment. So the function has no error either

Comment: So have you debugged to see where it fails? Add some var_dumps to see what `$row['name']` contains and see if all the if-statements validates properly. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes I checked everything. $row['name'] contains "testfile". testfile.php exists and the function is called testfile. I also changed the function call to $content .= testfile(); and that worked EDIT: I have just checked the return value of call_user_func again and it returns false...

Comment: problem found... spelling... don't ask please :D the function name wasn't testfile is was testflie Sorry to all and thanks to all